# Serilog Console Does Not Show Render Message

Tags: serilog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTYKX.png)as you can see the log that appear is wrong, it should show RENDER value but it show template value.
this is log configuration:

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithElkEnrich(httpContextAccessor)
                .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(elasticsearchSinkOptions)
                .WriteTo.Console(MinimumLogEventLevel(logOptions.ElkOptions.MinimumConsoleLevel))
                .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Could you add your call to `.Log(..)`? where you're actually logging the value

Comment: The code for `WithElkEnrich()` would also be useful, here (does the issue resolve if you remove it?)

Comment: Actually I need HttpContext in WithElkEnrich()